# wpf datagrid : remove dependency between main listing / child edit form?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have the following : a datagrid which DataContext is an object with a list of Customer objects. I pull the values from database.
To edit some customer, I click on a button in a row and open a new form with customer details. For now I pass the relevant customer object (thus reference) to child form DataContext.

I'm not fine with this because any modification in customer form are show in customers listing form.

I'd like both to be independent, and get customers listing form data refreshed only when I click on "save" button in child form (nothing done when I click on "cancel") that will trigger database reading for edited customer updated values.

Tell what you think would be right apart from these ideas :

1. Make a clone of Customer object and pass this clone to child form. I'm not fan of this.
2. Reread customer to edit from database to have a complete new object with relevant data. Seems not fun to ask to database again since my customer data is already completely read, in this case.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went on with my own way of doing this without working with delegates : [WPF : update parent form after canceling edit in child form (reset DataContext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800089/wpf-update-parent-form-after-canceling-edit-in-child-form-reset-datacontext/20800462#20800462)

A bit cumbersome but works.

I also used this nice way of cloning: [WPF : update parent form after canceling edit in child form (reset DataContext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800089/wpf-update-parent-form-after-canceling-edit-in-child-form-reset-datacontext/20800462#20800462)

But I did some changes: I added "where T : class" to the generic method signature.
I also simplified the code for testing for a null parameter :

```
// Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
if (source_ == null)
{
  return default(T);
 }
```